WPF project on .NET 8 missing 'Add Service Reference' from the 'Connected Services' menu
I have a WPF running on .NET 8.0. I understand that MS in their infinite wisdom have neglected VB developers when it comes to .NET core, but this is not .NET core.
Link to .NET core issue
According to the documentation adding a service reference has now moved from directly under solution explorer to Add > Connected Services and selecting 'Add Service Reference' - but only 'Service Dependencies' are available.


It's unfortunate, but there is not an option to Add Service Reference for VB.Net beyond .Net5.0. Furthermore, Microsoft has dropped web development for VB.Net VB.NET support for ASP.NET 5 (MVC6). In Visual Studio, you can only add WCF service references in C# for Net8.0.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide

Thanks for the Friday night cheerful news - wonderful how you can spend months building an app - then come to wire it up for data and it's bend over time! Brandy in looming near in my future - the drink not the stripper :-)
